# How to open port with Fastify?

Tags: nestjs, fastify

I'm trying to use Fastify with my project, but when I want to start the server, it isn't opening the specific port.

I'm creating the server like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { NestFastifyApplication, FastifyAdapter } from "@nestjs/platform-fastify";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );
  await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
}
bootstrap();
```

It says the application is successfully started, but when I check with **netstat -ano**,
the address(*0.0.0.0:3000*) isn't there.[image: The port that's supposed to open is 3000, the app's PID is 27324]

The server logs:
[image: Log1]
[image: Log2]
[image: Log3]
[image: Log4]

Comment: Does the server reply to an http request? The `netstat` may not run with the same permission you run the server

Comment: No, when I send a request with Postman, it says ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: Can you show the logs for your server? It sounds like it actually doesn't start up

Comment: I edited the answer so you can see the logs. The thing is, it is the same when I start it without Fastify, the only change is the PID.